# Is there still an XSS bug in JQuery1.12.4 when I upgrade my JQuery framework from 1.7.2 to 1.12.4?

Tags: jquery, xss

I have a old web project use jquery1.7.2 and BJUI framework.
There is an XSS bug in jquery1.7.2, I want resolve the XSS by upgrating my jQuery from jquery1.7.2 to 1.12.4.
I do not know whether the jQuery1.12.4 still have the XSS bug.
Please tell me that , dose the jQuery1.12.4 have the XSS issue?

best regards,
sorry for my poor english.

I download "jquery-migrate-1.4.1" and "jquery-1.12.4.js" and put the two files in my project folder, then import the js file :

```
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="BJUI/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script src="BJUI/other/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>    
<![endif]-->

<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-core.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-regional.zh-CN.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-frag.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-extends.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-basedrag.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-slidebar.js"></script>
<script src="BJUI/js/bjui-contextmenu.js"></script>
```